# How to pass a BlocProvider using Navigator in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, mobile-development

I am using a BlockProvider to manage the AuthService of my app and I'm currently working on a Setting Menu where there are some configurations that involve using this BlocProvider.

This BlocProvider is bein invoked in the MaterialApp func:

```
MaterialApp(
...
home: BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
        create: (context) => AuthBloc(FirebaseAuthProvider()),
        child: const HomePage(),
      ),
...
),
```

My `HomePage()` ensures the AuthState:

```
...
return BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is LoggedInAuthState) {
              return const InitialView();
            } else if (state is RegisteringAuthState) {
...
```

And then in the InitialView theres this AppBar in the Scaffold where the Button user the Navigator.of(context) to push the config menu:

```
AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(configRoute);
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.settings)),
        ],
      )
```

Now in the config menu:

```
 //! NO FUNCIONA
 TextButton(onPressed: () {
     context.read<AuthBloc>().add(
       const LogOutAuthEvent(),
     );
 }, child: Text(context.loc.logout))
```

When pressing the button an Error is thrown:
**Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this SettingsMenu Widget**

I tried to set this same button in my InitialView() and it works, so it has to do something with the Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

Once you're pushing a new page onto the stack, you are working within a new context. You can pass on the instance of the bloc as a variable to the new page and use that in children of that. This can become very serious boilerplate once you reach a certain complexity.

The solution to that is to simply move your provider to be the parent to MaterialApp. The bloc is now available in the whole context of that. Below Code uses a MultiBlocProvider, since you often have more than one Provider you want to have available globally.

```
MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
          BlocProvider<AuthBloc>.value(value: AuthBloc(FirebaseAuthProvider()),
        ], child: MaterialApp(...)),
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is that when you navigate to a new route, the BlocProvider needs to be accessible in the new route's widget tree. To pass the existing AuthBloc to the SettingsMenu when navigating, you can use BlocProvider.value to provide the current instance of AuthBloc to the new route.

Here is how you can modify your navigation call:

```
IconButton(
  onPressed: () {
     Navigator.of(context).push(
     MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
           return BlocProvider.value(
              value: BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context),
              child: SettingsMenu(), // Your settings menu widget
           );
        },
     ));
   },
   icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
)
```

Comment: Same problem. Error:
BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a AuthBloc.
No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>().

Comment: the BlocProvider<AuthBloc>. This is a common mistake; if you use the context from the widget where you're calling Navigator.of(context).push(...), that context may not have the AuthBloc in its widget tree. To fix this, you might need to use a Builder widget or a similar approach to obtain the correct context that has the necessary Bloc ancestor. If the AuthBloc is provided at the root of your app, make sure you are not using a context from a widget that is an ancestor to the BlocProvider in the widget tree.